# Is stethoscope sound mono- or stereosound?

Tags: acoustics

I am curious if the sound is monotonic. There are two things on my ears however.

Is [stethoscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stethoscope) sound mono- or stereosound?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert, but it seems to me that the it is mono-sound. Stereo means sound coming from two independent sound channels. As there is only one source, and both sounds are the same, I would consider it mono-sound. See [Wiki Stereo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereophonic_sound)

Comment: This is an excellent answer! I challenge people here to think if the source is really the same in all stethoscopes. It is possible to make stethoscope that have two sources - from two different angles - but not sure if any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I just **have** to say  LM--Y:
[http://www.amazon.com/Prestige-Medical-131-BLK-Stereo-Stethoscope/dp/B001ULDA9Q](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001ULDA9Q)

The word "stethoscope" is a generic term for any tool that enhances detection of subcutaneous sounds.  You can use a stick or metal rod, or you can use digital transducers with Bluetooth.

Now,  in a more general answer:  you are correct that "mono" or "stereo" is not a function of the number of earpieces.  I'd also point out that in the audio world,  the term for headphone sound is "binaural,"  which is not exactly the same as "stereo" loudspeakers.  There are significant differences in spatial perception.